# Random sampling with normal distribution from existing data in R

Tags: r, random, tidyverse, sample, normal-distribution

I have a large dataset of individuals who have rated some items (x1:x10). For each individual. the ratings have been combined into a total score (ranging 0-5). Now, I would like to draw two subsamples with the same sample size, in which the total score has a specific mean (1.5 and 3) and follows a normal distribution. Individuals might be part of both subsamples.

A guess to solve this, sampling with the outlined specifications from a vector (the total score) will work. Unfortunately, I have found only found different ways to draw random samples from a vector, but not a way to sample around a specific mean.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out I normal distribution would not be possible. Rather than I am looking way to sample a binomial distribution (directly from the data, without the work around of creating a similar distribution and matching).

Comment: If you want to sample from your data AND make it binomially distributed, the only two ways are 1) take loads of samples and keep the ones that match a binomial distribution or 2) take a binomial sample and pick members of your population whose score matches this sample (as my answer suggests). Neither of these is a "work around" - they are the only valid ways to sample your data AND match a distribution. The first way is hard, the second way is easier. They are both logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have normally distributed data on a discrete scale with hard limits. A sample drawn from a normal distribution with a mean between 0 and 5 would be symmetrical around the mean, would take coninuous rather than discrete values and would have a non-zero probability of containing values of less than zero and more than 5.

You want your sample to contain discrete values between zero and five and to have a central tendency around the mean. To emulate scores with a particular mean you need to sample from the **binomial distribution** using  `rbinom`.

```r
get_n_samples_averaging_m <- function(n, m)
{
  rbinom(n, 5, m/5)
}
```

Now you can do

```r
samp <- get_n_samples_averaging_m(40, 1.5)
print(samp)
# [1] 1 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 0 3 0 0 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 0 1 4 2 0 2 1 3 2 0 2 1
mean(samp)
# [1] 1.5
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but here's an issue someone might have with your answer: While you're right that the normal distribution is continuous rather than discrete, your proposed solution ignores what the OP is after: subsamples **of their data** meeting those criteria, not new independent binomial samples.

Comment: Thanks @duckmayr. I see your point. Still, it wouldn't be possible to draw a normally distributed sample from the data with the quoted means, so the binomial would be the closest to what the OP wanted. The OP could use the binomial to pull out matching candidates from their own data. I would have shown this, but didn't have the data in the example. Nevertheless, I genuinely appreciate your feedback.